# Reproduzir vídeo em BLOB do mysql

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, vídeo, blob

Olá, estou criando um site de uploads, e empaquei um uma parte, não é profissional só estou testando meus conhecimento e treinando. Meu problema é o seguinte, preciso fazer uma forma eficiente que o vídeo blob da database seja reproduzido no meu sem que fique bugando a barra de progresso, assim: https://playex.link/painel/upload/test.php?id=426612290166

Ou que tenha que baixar todo o arquivo e depois reproduzir como em uma DataURI...

Uma solução que eu tinha pensado era que criando um blob URI ele serviria para todas as pessoas, mas ele expira após a sessão fechar e se torna inválido.

Então, vocês podem me ajudar?

Meu código de testes atual é:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
$servidor = 'playex.link.mysql';
$usuario = 'playex_link';
$senha = '*******';
$banco = 'playex_link';

$mq = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);

$sel = 'SELECT * FROM Videos WHERE vid=' . $id ;
$re = $mq->query($sel);

while($row = $re->fetch_assoc()){
    print $row["q720"];
}

$mq->close();
?>
```

Comment: Só uma dica, descarte a pergunta anterior.